# Change Encoding in SWI-Prolog

Tags: prolog, artificial-intelligence

please somebody knows how to change the Encoding to US-ASCII in a SWI-Prolog Program ??

Comment: the online manual wasn't any help? you do know that UTF-8 is the same as US-ASCII for 7-bit characters right?

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, the Online Manual don't say what files i need to modify to change the Encoding and the command "encoding" don't work.

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx Also, the problem is that i need to write ASCII Extended codes with this command: "put(201)" where 201 is an extended ASCII Code.

Comment: how about the environment variable LANG mentioned in 2.18.1? I wonder why the encoding() command doesn't work

Comment: "extended ASCII"? I wasn't aware any such thing existed

Comment: Extended ASCII Codes all codes superiors to 127. See http://www.portalplanetasedna.com.ar/ascii.htm

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx Did you know the file were LANG variable is located ??

Comment: you set it in the environment. in the standard 'sh' shell it's:

LANG=ascii;
export LANG

Comment: Thanks for everything but i thing this is a death road! Am using Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

Seems quite straightforward according to [here](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/widechars.html) and [here](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%272.11%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/flags.html%27%29%29#flag%3aencoding).

You can explicitly load a pl file with a different encoding through options  inside `load_files/2`, check it out [here](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=load_files/2).

Comment: I'm get  ERROR: (f:/init:1):
        No permission to modify static_procedure `load_files/2'
% f:/init compiled 0.00 sec, 0 bytes

Comment: Posting the code that you're using will likely allow someone to tell you what you're doing wrong...

Comment: @Paulo Mora What im trying to do is write an extended ASCII char: ╔ their code is ALT + 201, but because the Encoding is wrong i get a rare 'E', somtehing like this: put(201).

Comment: The call "current_prolog_flag(encoding, Encoding)." will give you the current encoding, which you can change by calling "set_prolog_flag(encoding, NewEncoding).". See the SWI-Prolog manual for valid values for NewEncoding. Choose an encoding and lookup the code of the character you want to output for that encoding.